# AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'login_manager'

Tags: python, flask, logout

I'm working on a flask project where I log in a page by filling a login form . However when I try to logout from the page I get
    **AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'login_manager'** .
 After searching the flask documentation I saw how the login_manager module is used but the login form endpoint in the flask documentation was different from the one I created , so modifying my code seems the best solution . I have my login endpoint code down below :

```
@app.route('/simpleuser')    //returns the user page where I have a logout button 
def simpleuser():
    return render_template('simple.html')


@app.route('/login' , methods = ['GET' , 'POST'])  
def login():
     if request.method == 'POST':
          loginuser = users.find_one({"Email":request.form['Email']}) //if email exists
          if loginuser: //if password matches a hashed password 
               if  bcrypt.check_password_hash(loginuser['Password'],request.form['Password']):
                   session['Email'] = request.form['Email']
                     if loginuser["User"]=="Simple":  
                         return redirect(url_for('simpleuser')) //my page where I can logout 
               return 'Invalid email/password combination'
          return 'Invalid email'
    return render_template('login.html')            



@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
   # remove the email from the session if it's there
   session.pop('Email', None)
   return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

I would appreciate your guidance with helping me logout from the page correctly . Thank you in advance

Comment: @login_required is part of flask-login not on the Flask module

Answer (score 0):

It seems that by removing login_required the problem is immediatelly solved